# Word wrap problem in answers on IE 7

Tags: bug, status-declined, design, markdown, internet-explorer-7

Similar to this earlier reported word wrap bug in titles: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39852/possible-bug-with-title-word-wrap

I have now seen what might be the same problems in some answers, like these:

- [C++ pointer explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6096942/c-pointer-explanation/6097008#6097008)
- [Storing States in C++ Metaprogramming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6105994/storing-states-in-c-metaprogramming/6106030#6106030)

where the last word on one line gets repeated at the start of the next line.

The problem is seen both in IE7 on Windows and Safari on iPad, so it is unlikely to be a browser-specific problem.

Comment: I see this very frequently in IE7, @BO please can you retest in safari again?

Comment: similar question http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/54921/159256

Comment: @Damodar - Sorry, I don't have my iPad with me right now. One of the answers is mine, and I tried to edit it last night (using Safari) but it is correct in the edit window. Now I found another answer with the same problem.

Comment: I can't repro this with Safari on the iPhone. Unfortunately, no one has bought me an iPad yet.

Comment: http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/623/words-repeating-on-stackexchange/632#632 Same issue I reported on the wordpress SE site I believe

Comment: @Damodar - I now have access to Safari on an iPad again, and it works fine! It also works with Firefox 4 and IE8, which is what I have at home.

Comment: so this is specific issue with IE7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE7 is only minimally supported at this point, so unless the bug is materially harming basic participation on the site and/or children are being killed, we're not dedicating any engineering resources to minor IE7 issues.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently [this is an IE7 bug](http://blogs.sitepoint.com/the-ie-word-wrap-doppelganger-bug/). However, it can be fixed:

> On further investigation it appears to be a variety of the ‘haslayout’ bug, meaning adding either ‘zoom:1′ (invalid CSS) or ‘height:1%’ to the header will fix the bug without altering the padding.