# Word duplication in question that is not in source text on meta in IE7

Tags: bug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Word wrap problem in answers on IE 7 and iPad](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92471/word-wrap-problem-in-answers-on-ie-7-and-ipad)

I just posted [another question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94966/manually-entering-pre-tag-in-answer-edit-box-yields-script-error-in-ie-7) on meta, and thought I'd made a typo of saying "and and" in my post. Here's a screen shot, see the `and` at the end of the first line and beginning of the second:

[image: double and]

But when I went to edit my typo, that `and` did not exist:

[image: single and]

I have hit Ctrl-F5 in my browser but it did not resolve it.

When I copy and paste the text, the paste result has only one "and". This may mean the problem is actually in the browser and has nothing to do with SO at all.

I have duplicated this problem on another computer running the same version of IE.

One more thing: the source of the page has only a single `and`. Even if this occurs on multiple browsers it may still be a browser issue.

What do you think?

Comment: @wai My apologies for wasting anyone's time if this is a duplicate.

Comment: ie7 is only minimally supported at this time; it is literally our minimum browser spec.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently [this is an IE7 bug](http://blogs.sitepoint.com/the-ie-word-wrap-doppelganger-bug/). However, it can be fixed:

> On further investigation it appears to be a variety of the ‘haslayout’ bug, meaning adding either ‘zoom:1′ (invalid CSS) or ‘height:1%’ to the header will fix the bug without altering the padding.

So I think leaving this as a bug makes sense since it's fixable, though combining my question with other similar ones may be in order.